# Calculating Weight For Height Zscore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

So I am trying to create a `React` function that calculates Weight For Height Zscore.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
  calcWeightForHeightZscore(weightForHeightRef, height, weight) {
    let refSection;
    let formattedWHValue;
    if (height && weight) {
      height = parseFloat(height).toFixed(1);
    }
    const standardHeightMin = 45;
    const standardMaxHeight = 110;
    if (height < standardHeightMin || height > standardMaxHeight) {
      formattedWHValue = -4;
    } else {
      refSection = _.filter(weightForHeightRef, (refObject) => {
        return parseFloat(refObject['Length']).toFixed(1) === height;
      });
    }
  }
```

However I am faced with this error message:
`Cannot find name '_'.ts(2304)`

Any help how I could tackle this?

I expect it to return Z-score when used, but how would I approach tackling this error better

Comment: Did you install/import lodash?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `_` (which I assume is lodash), but it cannot be found.

Make sure you're installed the package and imported it

Comment: Yes I wonder if he even installed **Lodash**.